# How to access Database using domain name from windonws docker container

Tags: docker

Getting error as below:

`Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host *(my database server ip address), port *(database port) has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.`".

Database string:  `jdbc:sqlserver://dns:port;DatabaseName=testdb`

Using Docker Windows container

DockerfileWar:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/dv-2.war dv-2.war
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","dv-2.war"]
```

Build image from Project: docker build -f DockerfileWar -t dv-2war .

`docker run -p 8085:8085 dv-1war`

Getting above error while run the container.

`Note: If i used the IP address at DNS than it is working. But i want to do with DNS only.  Just for note database running on some other machine(Not on any container). Spring boot application running on docker windows container.`

Thanks, Dhaval

Comment: I can give a quick trick to try to resolve this .

1. are you able to connect using DNS from elsewhere ?
2. If above is true then are you able to ping the domain from docker terminal ?

Comment: Arun, Yes for point 1 I can connect using DNS anywhere. For point 2 container dont have any OS so how i can ping the domain?

Comment: There must be a base os image for every wrapper container , Try to google about that. From your point there is no database restriction , To confirm that there is problem in DNS resolving or network issue , try to connect using native SQL client from any container if it works , then its dns resolver is issue so you can add custom dns config while running docker ...

Comment: Thanks Arun for reply.

Now issue resolved. Here we need to give fully qualified domain name rather than just domain name. After given FQDN it is working fine. For check ping for your database server use below command. First you need to start docker container.  1. docker container start container-name   2. docker container exec container-name ping FQDN

Comment: happy for you mate !